# Cant populate list view with data from sqlite database

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, listview

I am attempting to learn Android development. And as a learning project I am creating a 'To Do' application.

I am trying to populate the list with data from my table and this is what I have so far:

ListCursorAdapter.java

```
    package com.ryansmurphy.listado;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by ryanmurphy on 24/02/15.
 */
public class ListCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public ListCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_todo, parent, false);
    }

    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // Find fields to populate in inflated template
        TextView todo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.todoText);
        // Extract properties from cursor
        String todoTextDB = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("todo"));
        // Populate fields with extracted properties
        todo.setText(todoTextDB);
    }
}
```

I am getting two error here:

1. On `extends cursor`. I get the error `Cannot resolve symbol`.
2. On `super(context, cursor, 0);`. I get the error `Object() in Object cannot be applied to`.

DatabaseHelper.java

```
package com.ryansmurphy.listado;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by ryanmurphy on 23/02/15.
 */
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "listado";

    // Table Name
    private static final String TABLE_TODO = "todos";


    // Column names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_TODO = "todo";
    private static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";


    // Table Create Statements
    // Todo table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TODO = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_TODO + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TODO
            + " TEXT," + KEY_STATUS + " INTEGER," + KEY_CREATED_AT
            + " DATETIME" + ")";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // creating required table
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TODO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // on upgrade drop older tables
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TODO);

        // create new tables
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addRecord()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("todo", "todo example");
        values.put("status", "not completed");
        database.insert("todos", null, values);
        database.close();
    }

    public Cursor getAll()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from todos",null);
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

Now my listview individual row xml:
list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/todoText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:padding="6dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

ActivityMain.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView android:text="To Do List" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.Java

```
package com.ryansmurphy.listado;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Setup cursor adapter using cursor from last step
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper();
        Cursor allRows = db.getAll();
        ListCursorAdapter todoAdapter = new ListCursorAdapter(this, allRows);
        //Attach cursor adapter to the ListView
        lvItems.setAdapter(todoAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if(id == R.id.addItem)
        {
            addItem();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void addItem()
    {
        Intent addItemIntent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddItem.class);
        startActivity(addItemIntent);
    }
}
```

I am getting two errors here:

1. On `DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper();`. I get the error `DatabaseHelper(Context) in DatabaseHelper cannot be applied`.
2. On `lvItems.setAdapter(todoAdapter);`. I get the error `setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter) in ListView cannot be applied`.

The above I have got from just googling and trying and trying. I have never really known what I have been doing from the start but I am slowly picking this up and am wondering if you guys can help me out after getting this far. Thanks

Comment: For this line `DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper();` in your `MainActivity`, you should pass a `Context` object. `ActionBarActivity` is a sub class of `Context`, so you can pass `this` as `Context`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code to a new project and made a few alterations to get it working. There were some areas I stripped back completely - for instance, the `getAll()` method, and I replaced it with a query in `MainActivity`. [Here](http://oi60.tinypic.com/118errn.jpg) is what the application looks like on first loading, and [here](http://oi60.tinypic.com/142ssxv.jpg) is how it looks after hitting "add" a few times.

For what it's worth, I think there are easier ways to achieve this - for instance, by using `SimpleCursorAdapter`, which would negate the need to created your own custom `Adapter` class, and by having your `MainActivity` extend `ListActivity` or `ListFragment`. However, I've stuck to using your method.

I made the following small changes to DatabaseHelper, in addition to deleting the `getAll()` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE todos (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, todo TEXT, status INTEGER, created_at INTEGER);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onUpgrade: this is  not required.");
}
```

I changed the lengthy concatenated `String CEATE_TABLE_TODO` because I find it easier to read. I also changed columns so that they contain a mix of text and numbers. I also swapped out the `onUpgrade()` method for a simple error message, as we shouldn't use `onUpgrade()` during our tests as it is only required when upgrading an app that has already shipped.

I made some small changes to `ListCursorAdapter` so that the information shows something useful - in this case, the `String` located at `cursor.getString(1)` (which is column one).

```
public class ListCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

LayoutInflater inflater;

public ListCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView todo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.todoText);
    String todoTextDB = cursor.getString(1);
    todo.setText(todoTextDB);
}
}
```

In `MainActivity`, your `DatabaseHelper` requires a `context` parameter, which I achieve by using `this`. (You can see this if you look back to your constructor in `DatabaseHelper`:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

That aside, the only major change I did was to move the `DatabaseHelper` `query` into `MainActivity`, which I put inside a method called `runCursor()` so we can update our `ListView` every time we add a new item with `addItem()`.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

DatabaseHelper db;
ListView lv;
ListCursorAdapter adapter;
Cursor allRows;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new ListCursorAdapter(this, runCursor());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    if (allRows != null) {
        allRows.close();
    }
    adapter.getCursor().close();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    if(id == R.id.addItem)
    {
        addItem();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void addItem()
{
   db.addRecord();
    adapter.changeCursor(runCursor());
}

Cursor runCursor() {
    Cursor allRows = null;
    allRows = db.getReadableDatabase().query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_TODO,
            new String[] {DatabaseHelper.KEY_ID, DatabaseHelper.KEY_TODO},
            null, null, null, null, null);
    return allRows;
    }
}
```

I should also mention that I explicitly close any cursor objects by overriding onDestroy() as they can be prone to memory leaks. One final word too that I haven't done here is that it is best move any cursor query() to a background thread, like an `AsyncTask`. There's more information on `Cursor` on the [Android Developer page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) that I'd recommend! hope this was useful!

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. I used alot of your changes, I hope you dont mind. However, I took your advice and used simplecursoradapter and its better. Thanks again